# Sum Qtys from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

The view below does not return correct results. I am trying to get the sum of Picked, Printed & Scanned grouped by Plan_Id & PartNum. I need to return the correct totals regardless if there are corresponding records in the child tables. I know how to do it if I use three different views and join them, but how do i do it all in a single view? Any help appreciated.

```
SELECT
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId` AS `PlanId`,
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum` AS `PartNum`,
    sum(`prod_plan`.`Prp_Picked`) AS `Picked`,
    sum(`printed`.`PtQty`) AS `Printed`,
    sum(`scanned`.`PtQty`) AS `Scanned`
FROM
    (
        (
            `prod_plan`
            LEFT JOIN `product_trans` `printed` ON (
                (
                    (
                        `printed`.`PtPlanId` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId`
                    )
                    AND (
                        `printed`.`PtPartNum` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum`
                    )
                )
            )
        )
            LEFT JOIN `product_trans` `scanned` ON (
            (
            (
                `scanned`.`PtPlanId` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId`
            )
            AND (
                `scanned`.`PtPartNum` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum`
            )
        )
    )
)
WHERE
    (
        (
            `printed`.`PtPart` = 'Barcode Print'
        )
        AND (
            `scanned`.`PtPart` = 'Barcode Scan'
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId`,
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done. Below are 3 views that work correctly.

v_trans_printed:

```
SELECT
product_trans.PtPlanId AS PlanId,
product_trans.PtLot AS Lot,
product_trans.PtPartNum AS PartNum,
Sum(product_trans.PtQty) AS Printed
FROM
product_trans
WHERE
product_trans.PtPart = 'Barcode Print'
GROUP BY
product_trans.PtPlanId,
product_trans.PtLot,
product_trans.PtPartNum
```

v_trans_scanned:

```
SELECT
product_trans.PtPlanId AS PlanId,
product_trans.PtLot AS Lot,
product_trans.PtPartNum AS PartNum,
Sum(product_trans.PtQty) AS Scanned
FROM
product_trans
WHERE
product_trans.PtPart = 'Barcode Scan'
GROUP BY
product_trans.PtPlanId,
product_trans.PtLot,
product_trans.PtPartNum
```

And here I put them all together. This returns the correct results:

```
vSELECT
prod_plan.Prp_ProdPlanId AS PlanId,
prod_plan.Prp_Lot AS Lot,
prod_plan.Prp_PartNum AS PartNum,
Sum(prod_plan.Prp_Picked) AS Picked,
Printed.Printed AS Printed,
Scanned.Scanned AS Scanned
FROM
prod_plan
LEFT JOIN v_trans_printed AS Printed ON Printed.PlanId = prod_plan.Prp_ProdPlanId AND Printed.Lot = prod_plan.Prp_Lot AND Printed.PartNum = prod_plan.Prp_PartNum
LEFT JOIN v_trans_scanned AS Scanned ON Scanned.PlanId = prod_plan.Prp_ProdPlanId AND Scanned.Lot = prod_plan.Prp_Lot AND Scanned.PartNum = prod_plan.Prp_PartNum
GROUP BY
prod_plan.Prp_ProdPlanId,
prod_plan.Prp_Lot,
prod_plan.Prp_PartNum
```

### But it would be better if I could use one view.

Note: I left out Lot originally by accident. But it didn't affect the results w. the sample data set.

Comment: I hated to check my own solution because it is rather clumsy. Oh well. Feel free to improve. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `PtPart` in the `ON` clauses. Otherwise, you won't get the rows with no matches in the child tables, because those columns will be `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId` AS `PlanId`,
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum` AS `PartNum`,
    sum(`prod_plan`.`Prp_Picked`) AS `Picked`,
    sum(`printed`.`PtQty`) AS `Printed`,
    sum(`scanned`.`PtQty`) AS `Scanned`
FROM `prod_plan`
LEFT JOIN `product_trans` `printed`
ON `printed`.`PtPlanId` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId`
    AND `printed`.`PtPartNum` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum`
    AND `printed`.`PtPart` = 'Barcode Print'
LEFT JOIN `product_trans` `scanned`
ON `scanned`.`PtPlanId` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId`
    AND `scanned`.`PtPartNum` = `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum`
    AND `scanned`.`PtPart` = 'Barcode Scan'
GROUP BY
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_ProdPlanId`,
    `prod_plan`.`Prp_PartNum`
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Barmar. But your solution still returns the wrong results. e.g. in Plan_id 10, PartNum 1293 has only 9 Picked & 2 Printed. But the view returns 45 Picked & 10 Printed. 10 is the total printed for ALL lots. I don't know how it returns 45 for picked. The total for ALL Lots Picked for PartNum 1293 is only 39! is there any reason why this might be so?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?